# How to expand a variable as several space separated program arguments

Tags: powershell

Dears,

I have an environment variable containing all the arguments to pass to a program.
VAR_NAME=/arg1 /arg2 /arg3 ...

I tried invoking the program using:

```
program $Env.VAR_NAME
```

Unfortunately the environment variable expends to a single argument.

Thanks.

Comment: you could try `program ($Env.VAR_NAME -split ' ')` - this will return a list of your arguments as a string array

Comment: Thanks, your solution works just fine.

Comment: Glad to help you, added the answer

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74757686/1147688) I provide a few different methods, to expand *commandlet* arguments, using variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the environment variable to return a list of arguments:

```
program ($Env.VAR_NAME -split ' ')
```

Comment: Nicely done; just to clarify the constraints: `program` is assumed to be an _external_ program rather than a PowerShell command, and simple splitting by spaces won't work if the value contains quoted arguments that have embedded spaces themselves - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69170814/45375) to a related question tries to cover all angles. As an aside: `program (-split $Env.VAR_NAME)` provides more flexibility, because it also tolerates multiple spaces between embedded arguments and ignore leading and trailing whitespace.