# Powershell, use (space-separated) string as arguments to a program

Tags: string, powershell, parameter-passing

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438339/how-to-expand-a-variable-as-several-space-separated-program-arguments) and it doesn't solve my problem.

I have a space-separated string, let's say `$MyString = "arg1 arg2"`. Suppose I have a command line program called `MyProgram`, which accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments, so it can be run like `MyProgram arg1 arg2`. However doing `MyProgram $MyString` doesn't work, and neither does `MyProgram ($MyString -split ' ')` nor `MyProgram $($MyString -split ' ')`. I get the same error which basically says that it doesn't recognise the argument "arg1 arg2", which I guess is because it still thinks it's one argument containing a space rather than two arguments. In practice, `$MyString` may be quite huge and is read from a file. How do I make this work?

Comment: There are other long and good-looking answers that I haven't made time to read yet and I feel bad because they've clearly put in a lot of effort and I felt conceited to accept my own answer without reading theirs LOL.

Comment: Well, you can still take the time, and you can change the accepted answer anytime. Either way, I encourage you to improve your own answer based on the feedback given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh I just found out how LOL. I should have thought of this sooner; basically, just use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) The following worked for me:

```
$MyArray = $($MyString -split " ")
MyProgram @MyArray
```

Explanation: The first line converts the string into an array of strings split by space (" "); The `$(...)` notation around a command captures the output of the command, which I then assign to `$MyArray`. Then, instead of using `$MyArray` with a dollar sign `$`, I use it with `@` to splat the array of strings into arguments for `MyProgram`.

Comment: Kudos on coming back to update with your solution, many users don't do this :) You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676) I wrote on another question regarding how to splat useful as well, it explains how to splat both named and positional parameters, and how to use them together.

Comment: When calling _PowerShell_ commands you do indeed need splatting to pass an array's elements as individual, positional arguments. By contrast, you don't when calling an _external program_, as in the post you link to. Note that, unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, `$(...)` in PowerShell is rarely needed outside of `"..."` strings; `(...)` is usually sufficient and preferable, but here you need neither: `$MyArray = $MyString -split " "`, or, for more flexibility, `$MyArray = -split $MyString`

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for the clarification. Why is `(...)` preferred over `$(...)`? I would have thought that the explicitness of `$(...)` might make it preferable.

Comment: Pipeline logic is applied to the output from `$(...)`, which means that array expressions are enumerated and rebuilt, and single-element arrays are unwrapped - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375) for details. As for readability: While`$(...)` is familiar from POSIX-compatible shells, to me `(...)` is more readable (less noisy).

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

For **calling *PowerShell* commands** you indeed **need [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) in order to pass the *elements* of an array as *individual, positional* arguments**; this requires defining the array in an *auxiliary variable* that can then be passed with sigil `@` in lieu of `$` to request splatting:

```
$myArray = -split $myString   # See below for limitations, bottom section for fix
MyPowerShellCommand @myArray  # Array elements are passed as indiv. arguments.
```

While this technique also works **with *external programs***, it isn't strictly necessary there, and **you can pass an array *directly*** to achieve the same effect:

```
MyExternalProgram (-split $myString) # Array elements are passed as indiv. args.
```

<sup>Note that `(...)` rather than `$(...)` is used to pass the  expression as an argument. `(...)` is usually sufficient and generally preferable, because `$(...)` can have side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375) for details.</sup>

---

Just to bring the [post you link to in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438339/how-to-expand-a-variable-as-several-space-separated-program-arguments) and [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166398/45375) together:

First, to be clear: neither answer, due to splitting by *spaces only* will deal properly with arguments inside the argument-list string that have *embedded spaces* (and therefore, of necessity use *embedded quoting*), e.g., `` $myString = "arg1 `"arg2 with spaces`" arg3" `` would not work as expected - see the bottom section for a solution.

Leaving that aside, the difference is:

- **When calling an *external program***, as in the linked post, **passing an *array* causes *each element to become its own argument***.

  - That is, `myExternalProgram (-split $MyString)` would work.
  - Note that I'm using the *unary* form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) for more flexible tokenization, which splits by *any non-empty run of whitespace* while ignoring leading and trailing whitespace (same as `awk`'s default behavior).
- **When calling a *PowerShell* command**, as in your case, **an array is by default passed *as-is*, as a whole, as a *single* argument**.

  - To achieve the same effect as with external programs, i.e. **to pass the array's elements as individual, positional arguments, you indeed have to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)**, i.e. you have to:

    - save the array in a *variable* first: `$myArray = -split $myString`,
    - which you can then pass as as a splatted argument by using `@` instead of `$` as the sigil: `MyPowerShellCommand @myArray`
  - Do note that **when calling *PowerShell* commands** it is more common - and more robust - to **use [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)- rather than an array-based splatting**, as it **allows you to explicitly bind to parameters *by name* rather than *by position*** - and PowerShell commands often have parameters that can *only* be bound by name.

    - E.g., if `MyPowerShellCommand` accepts parameters `-Foo` and `-Bar`, you could use:
      `$myArgs = @{ Foo='foo value'; Bar='bar value '}; MyPowerShellCommand @myArgs`

---

**If you do want to handle argument-list strings that have arguments with *embedded quoting***:

```
$myString = 'arg1 "arg2 with spaces" arg3'

$myArray = (Invoke-Expression ('Write-Output -- ' + $myString -replace '\$', "`0")) -replace "`0", '$$'
```

<sup>Note: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), but the extra precautions taken in this particular command make its use safe.</sup>

`$myArray` is then a 3-element array with verbatim elements `arg1`, `arg2 with spaces` and `arg3`, which can again be used as shown above.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423062/45375) for an explanation of the technique.

Answer (score 0):

These work for me ($args is reserved).  -split on the left side splits on whitespace.  Or you can get-content from a file where each argument is on a seperate line.  You might run into a limit with how long a commandline can be.  Piping that list in or loading it from a file might be a better approach.

```
echo hi > file.txt

$args2 = 'hi','file.txt'
findstr $args2
# hi

$args2 = 'hi','file.txt'
& findstr $args2
# hi

$args2 = 'hi file.txt'
findstr (-split $args2)
# hi

findstr ($args2 -split ' ')
# hi
```